# How to split my string "a!b!" into a!, b! in python?

Tags: python, string, split

Is it possible to separate the string "a!b!" into two strings "a!" and "b!" and store that in a list? I have tried the split() function (and even with the delimiter "!"), but it doesn't seem to give me the right result that I want. Also, the character "!" could be any character.

Comment: @TDG I can use the re.split() function and just manipulate the results a bit to get the result that I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```
string = 'a!ab!b!'
deliminator = '!'
word_list = [section+deliminator for section in string.split(deliminator) if section]
print(word_list)
```

Output :

```
['a!', 'ab!', 'b!']
```

Answer (score 0):

split() is used when you need to seperate a string with particular character. If you want split a string into half, Try this

```
s = "a!b!"
l = [s[ : len(s)//2], s[len(s)//2 : ]]

# output : ["a!", "b!"]
```

Comment: What will happen if the input is 'ab!ab!a!'?